# How to create a button event on Ubuntu SDK

Tags: sdk

I've downloaded the Ubuntu SDK to create apps in my spare time, and I've started converting a console app of a binary converter I made to one with a GUI. So I've dropped the edits, buttons and what not but for my one button that converts I don't know how to make the event. I've tried double clicking (which works in so many other rad environments) but in this it just goes to change the properties of the button. I've looked around on the menus and drop downs but can't find anything. All help is appreciated, thank you.

PS: This is in fact a desktop application not a mobile one.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to do it via the GUI, but if you go to edit mode, and go to the button, you can change the onClicked event.

```
Button {
    iconSource: "icon.png"
    text: "Icon on left"
    iconPosition: "left"
    onClicked: print("clicked text and icon Button")
}
```

You can find more information here: http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/devel/ubuntu-13.10/qml/ui-toolkit/qml-ubuntu-components0-button.html